Does std::filesystem::last_write_time require a minimum Windows 10 version
I use std::filesystem::last_write_time which throws an exception on various Windows installations.
Minimal code example:
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

int main()
{
    auto last_write_time = std::filesystem::temp_directory_path() / "last_write_time.txt";
    std::ofstream(last_write_time.c_str()) << "Hello, World!";

    try
    {
        auto ftime = std::filesystem::last_write_time(last_write_time);
        std::cout << ftime << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    std::filesystem::remove(last_write_time);
}




Machine Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSB Version 1607 throws exception.what() "unknown error"




Machine Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSB Version 1607 throws exception.what() "The specified module could not be found."


Windows 7 Embedded Standard 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601 throws exception.what() "The specified module could not be found."
Windows 10 Pro Version 22H2 works as expected
Windows 11 Enterprise Version 23H2 works as expected

My conclusion is that std::filesystem::last_write_time requires a minimum Windows10 version as std::chrono::current_zone does
VS2019 16.10 Release notes
VS 2019 16.10 Release notes screenshot snippet

Maybe the used SDK is the issue?

Just a note: Your minimal code is actually less than minimal, see [mcve].

Does it work if you change std::cout << ftime to std::cout << ftime.time_since_epoch().count()?

Did you link with the static runtime support?  If not did you install the latest redistributable runtime support ?

@IS4 I use Windows SDK Version 10.0.22621.0 any suggestions which I should try?
@cpplearner Yes it works and with this I have a workaround I can use std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(file.last_write_time.time_since_epoch().count() instead of std::chrono::clock_cast<std::chrono::system_clock>(file.last_write_time)

@RichardCritten I'm not familiar with project settings. Do you mean Use of MFC? This is set to "Use Standard Windows Libraries" and I copied the vc*.dll next to the runtime

No the /MD, /MT, /LD (Use Run-Time Library) settings.  And never copy the MSVC runtime DLL(s) always use the MS provided Runtime Redist Package.

std::filesystem::last_write_time doesn't require a minimum Windows version, but to convert the resulting file_time to sys_time needs the leap second database, and thus requires Windows 10 version 1809 or later. (In your minimal code example, it is std::cout << ftime that internally triggers a conversion to sys_time.)
This is because MSVC STL implements the conversion from file_time to sys_time using two steps: first it converts file_time to utc_time (which is leap-second-aware); then it converts utc_time to sys_time (which is not leap-second-aware). The second step requires the leap second database in order to work correctly.
You can work around this by implementing the conversion on your own, but be aware that:

file_time and sys_time have different epochs.
The result might be slightly incorrect if a leap second is inserted in the future.


Very interesting (and correct) answer.  file_time does indeed convert to sys_time via utc_time, requiring the leap second database.  But file_time doesn't actually count leap seconds. (https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qon9fW1fc)  I'm left wondering why file_time doesn't directly convert to sys_time.  This would be more efficient and not require the leap second database.  This is an open question, and not directed at @cpplearner.

@HowardHinnant Oh, I happen to know the answer: Windows's file_time is conditionally leap-second-aware (depends on the OS version, the registry key HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\LeapSecondInformation, and then only if the leap second comes after 2018). Nonetheless, the implementer chose to define the conversion to utc_clock in order not to lose leap second information.

(For the reference, there have been no leap seconds since 2018.)

Very interesting, thanks!
